# Nginx consumes Upgrade header after proxy_pass

Tags: django, nginx, websocket, uwsgi

So I have been banging my head against the wall for the better part of 2 days, please help.

I am attempting to establish a Websocket connection using this
[django-websocket-redis](http://django-websocket-redis.readthedocs.org/en/latest/running.html#django-with-websockets-for-redis-behind-nginx-using-uwsgi) configuration.
There are 2 instances of uwsgi running, one for the website and one for the websocket communication.

I used wireshark  heavily to find out what exactly is happening, and apparently nginx is eating the headers "Connection: Upgrade" and "Upgrade: websocket".

here is the critical nginx config part:

```
upstream websocket {
    server 127.0.0.1:9868;
}

location /ws/ {
    proxy_pass_request_headers      on;
    access_log off;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_pass http://websocket;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Upgrade websocket;
}
```

As you can see on those 2 [screenshots](http://imgur.com/HPrtFCW&PtJbJ14), tcpdump of internal communication shows that the handshake works nicely. but in my browser (second image) the headers are missing.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated. I am truly stuck here :(

Versions:

```
nginx - 1.7.4
uwsgi - 2.0.7
```

pip freeze:
    Django==1.7
    MySQL-python==1.2.5
    django-redis-sessions==0.4.0
    django-websocket-redis==0.4.2
    gevent==1.0.1
    greenlet==0.4.4
    redis==2.10.3
    six==1.8.0
    uWSGI==2.0.7
    wsgiref==0.1.2

Comment: not near my laptop, but have you tried placing your connection Upgrade outside location block?

Comment: The header Connection: Upgrade should only be set if the request was made on the websocket address (domain/ws/[facility-params]). Please explain a little what you expect the header to do outside the location block.

Comment: you said this whole worker was for tthe websocket only?

Comment: sorry forgot what I said. think I completely misunderstood your question

Comment: correct. the nginx config you see is only for the websocket connections which use a different uwsgi process than the main page. By the way the Main page is accessed using uwsgi_pass on a different port of 127.0.0.1

Comment: ok now back home. read your images, now I'm confused. what header are you missing? they look like 1 request & 1 response

Comment: The missing headers are "Connection: Upgrade" and "Upgrade: websocket". You will notice, that in the second image (firefox) in the response headers these are missing.

Comment: Ah ok I completely misunderstood you. I never realized there is a SECOND image -- thought you combined both request+response and I was struggling to see what problem there was

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62444/discussion-between-anzel-and-dershodan).

Comment: That is the default behaviour of a proxy. The "Connection" header indicates other header that needs to be removed in the next hoop, and since a proxy is a hoop, it removes the indicated header, that is "Upgrade". A way of avoiding this is using WSS:// (websocket over SSL). Unfortunately I don't how to configure ngix to not to do this, please keep us posted.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do:
Do you want the user's browser to see the `Upgrade` and `Connection` headers or do you want django to see those headers?
With the `proxy_set_header` django will see those headers, but the user will not.

Comment: @vtortola I read that before. The thing is, that according to countless tutorials this is the way you proxy pass the websocket connection. And the stranges thing is, that on other nginx configurations (e.g. locally on my machine) the proxy pass works and the headers are not removed on their way back.

Comment: @qff The idea behind this configutation is, that normal http requests go to one "directory" and websocket connection attempts (always on /ws/....) are proxy passed to a module called [django-websocket-redis](http://django-websocket-redis.readthedocs.org/en/latest/running.html#django-with-websockets-for-redis-behind-nginx-using-uwsgi/) which "can" be hosted separately (in this case it isn't).

Comment: If it works locally... have you consider you may have another proxy in the way when deployed?

Comment: @vtortola Good hint, thanks. Ill check my apache settings now. Best guess since ~30 hours of futile attemts...

Answer (score 3):

I would use gunicorn for deploying a django application, but anyway.

I remembered that I saw this on the gunicorn docs:

> If you want to be able to handle streaming request/responses or other
>   fancy features like Comet, Long polling, or Web sockets, you need to
>   turn off the proxy buffering. When you do this you must run with one
>   of the async worker classes.
>
> To turn off buffering, you only need to add proxy_buffering off; to
>   your location block:

In your location would be:

```
location /ws/ {
    proxy_pass_request_headers      on;
    access_log off;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_pass http://websocket;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Upgrade websocket;
}
```

Link to the guide of gunicorn for deploying in nginx.
http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/deploy.html?highlight=header

Hope this helps

Comment: Unfortunately the header is still dropped. WSS is the way to go.

Comment: Apologies for the necro but the [official documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html) has an example on how to do this and it does work.  I wonder if the solution above had `"Upgrade"` instead of `"upgrade"` as in the documentation?  Hopefully this will help someone else.